# Why doesn't Internet Explorer trigger the submit event consistently?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, internet-explorer

Found an apparent bug in Internet Explorer today, but unable to verify via research. Has anybody encountered this and/or can explain please?

**Synopsis**

Internet Explorer (at least 9 and 11) does not always trigger (or handle?) the submit event. Noticed a case where clicking submit button somewhat quickly causes some submits to be skipped. This issue is not noticed in Chrome and Firefox.

**Test case**

- Simple form with single input and single submit button.
- Javascript handler on form submit: display `submit`, and then return false
- Javascript handles on click of submit button: display `click`
- jQuery used for clarity (same issue is noticed with equivalent non-jQuery solution)
- To execute test, user must quickly double-click the Submit button and observe which events are handled.

**Test results**

Firefox and Chrome work as expected:

```
click
submit
click
submit
```

Internet Explorer does something weird (as usual):

```
click
submit
click
```

There is no second submit! With IE only, the client handler is not called, and Fiddler shows the request never happens in the production environment. (Note that this example code won't actually POST the request though, due to `return false`.)

Working snippet: please scroll down and click Run Snippet, then try double clicking quickly on the Submit button, and observe the results. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/30rac2xm/2/)

```js
feedback = function (t) {
    $div = $("<div class='line'></div>");
    $div.html(t);
    $("#feedback").append($div);
};
$("#theForm").on("submit", function (e) {
    feedback("submit");
    return false; // don't actually submit form, or SO chokes
});
$("#btnSubmit").on("click", function (e) {
    feedback("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='theForm' action="DISABLED BY RETURN FALSE" method="POST">
    <input type='text' />
    <input id='btnSubmit' type='submit' />
</form>
<div id='feedback'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with this, but I'm guessing you are trying to prevent double submissions of the form? In that case maybe you could use something like:

```
feedback = function (t) {
    $div = $("<div class='line'></div>");
    $div.html(t);
    $("#feedback").append($div);
};
$("#theForm").on("submit", function (e) {
    feedback("submit only once");
    $(this).find("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```